# How to recreate in embedded Derby database a table for EJB Timer Service in GlassFish 4?

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, ejb, derby

I'm using `Java EE 7`, `GlassFish 4`, `EJB 3.1`.

Unless I'm missing something, it seems that `embedded Derby database` table that is supposed to support persistence for `EJB Timer Service` (**EJB_*TIMER*_TBL**) is missing. I discovered it when for the first time used `@Schedule` annotation and started getting deployment errors  and then run-time `java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available`.

The default connection `jdbc/__TimerPool` was not setup as `Timer Datasource` (the field was blank) in Sever Configuration, so I put it there.

In `...\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\ejb\ejb-timer-service-app` directory I found `ejb-timer-service-app___EJB__Timer__App_createDDL.jdbc` file that looks like an SQL Script to create this table.

I could not find clear guidelines how to use this script or recreate the table in any other way.

In `...\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\databases\ejbtimer` directory I currently have the following:

- 2 files: **db.lck** and **service propertes**
- 3 folders: **log**, **seg0**, **tmp**.

If somebody had already gone through the procedure or just knows how to do it, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This link seems to cover it for UNIX: http://www.nolte-schamm.za.net/2013/01/glassfish-recreate-ejb-derby-timer-database/

Comment: The link above is no longer working, however I found this blog post with instructions that worked for me: http://www.dydx.co.za/2013/01/glassfish-recreate-ejb-derby-timer-database/

Comment: Both links are not working, @PM77-1 Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @TinusJackson - No, I did not go back to that problem since.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://www.dydx.de/index.php/2016/10/30/glassfish-recreate-ejb-derby-timer-database/ guess it was same link as comment #2

Comment: @TinusJackson - My original post goes back to 2013 (five years old) and I haven't revisited the issue since.